# Does there exist a prime $p > 5$ such that $3p+1 = 2^n, n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Looking at prime factorization, and I was wondering if, in general, there were any primes larger than 5 so that 3 times the prime plus one is a power of two.

If there is, is there a method of determining that without multiplication - i.e. is there a pattern in which they appear?

I have tested all the low primes and have not found one that does this like $5$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $3p+1=2^n$ then $2^n\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and hence $n$ is even. Let$n=2m$.

Then 
$$3p=2^{2m}-1=(2^m-1)(2^m+1)$$

This means that either 
$$2^m-1=1 \\
2^m+1=3p$$
which is not possible, or 
$$2^m-1=3 \\
2^m+1=p$$
which gives $p=5$.

Therefore, $p=5$ is the only possibility.

Comment: D'Oh!..............+1